# Limit slackbot response to a channel?

Tags: slack, bot

I know how to program a slackbot response when anyone mentions certain words in a comment. Is it possible to limit this to certain channels?

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202026038-Slackbot-your-assistant-notepad-programmable-bot

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't the most elegant place for feature information, according to this [Twitter thread involving SlackHQ](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/501851378390941696), there is no way to limit Slackbot at the channel level.

Edit: this may not suit your needs but there is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slack-bot-filter/blephhkggdennbfmdcjmlfimedknghfc?hl=en) for filtering bot messages at the channel level. I haven't tried it so I can't personally vouch for it. If you really need this Slackbot feature then one option is to fork the [extension on Github](https://github.com/call-a3/slack-filter-bots) and modify the code so that only certain Slackbot messages are filtered.